# WPF styling a textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I'm trying to create a style for my textbox :

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"   Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="100" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="25" />
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop"  Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource CouleurBouton}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Helvetica" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource CouleurTexte}" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                    <Border Name="Border"
                CornerRadius="7"
                Padding="2"
                BorderThickness="2"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                        <ScrollViewer Margin="0"
                        x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <!-- Mouse Over -->
                                <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource CouleurBoutonHover}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource CouleurTexte}" />
                        </MultiTrigger>

                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <!-- Desactivé-->
                                <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource CouleurBoutonDisabled}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource CouleurBoutonDisabled}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>

                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <!-- Focus-->
                                <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                                <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="True" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource CouleurBoutonPressed}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource CouleurTexte}" />
                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

This style fits my needs but I'd like to customize the color of the "cursor" (vertical line) in the textbox (pointed in this image :[image]

How can I do this ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `CaretBrush` property in style for the desired color

example

```
<Setter Property="CaretBrush" Value="Aqua" />
```